# Using C++ to interface with a line-scan camera at 3000Hz, and process / display the data

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, camera

Several months ago, I started working on a project to develop an algorithm to process data acquired from a linescan camera device (e.g., a line of 384 pixels every 300us).  Since I am an engineer and not a programmer, I started working with Python to minimize the learning curve.  With help from SX, I successfully built a Python application (that ended up being more than 2000 lines of code) and successfully created an image processing algorithm to work with the data.  I impressed the customer and they want to take it to the next level.  Now, I need it to be real-time... and that means C++.  I got Koenig and Moo's Accelerated C++ and started reading.  So, please go easy on me.  I love to learn to program, but I have no formal training.  I'm doing the best I can!

I now have a C++ prototype GUI (using Qt) wrapped around all the libraries needed to communicate with the camera via a CameraLink interface.  The acquisition code lives in its own thread and emits signals to the GUI.  So, I have the fundamentals in place.  I can acquire as many lines of data as I wish with my current code, but I am now trying to figure out how to build an application around that.  Even wrote a custom makefile that works with Qt (MOCing, etc.)

Anyway, for the application, I would like two modes (these are the QUESTIONS):

(1) A "live" view... where the linescan data is displayed in real time by the GUI.  I was thinking about using a circular buffer (e.g., Boost::circular_buffer) to hold the data in real time, and simply pass a copy of the buffer (memcpy?) to the GUI via an emitted signal.  Is this tenable?  I feel the copy of the buffer is necessary since the circular buffer will change every 300us or so and I don't know the main event loop can keep up.  Again, the data acquisition lives in its own thread.  Does it have to be more complicated than that?  Will I have to pop data from the buffer as it is read instead of using a circular buffer?  I felt a circular buffer was the way to go since that is exactly the kind of image I want to display.

(2) A data processing mode... where the linescan data is emitted in blocks (i.e., 384 x 384) pixels.  At a scan rate of 300us (~3,333 Hz), that is a block or frame every 100ms or so.  In that 100ms, I'll need to do normalization of data, object detection, thresholding, etc.  I'm planning on running this on a Linux box running real-time kernel patch.  I think it should keep up.  I'll need to communicate between the data acquisition and data processing threads...  do I need sockets for this?

I'm looking for advice here on how to get started with these two pieces.  The second one is more critical, but the first will help me visualize what is going on.  Ultimately, I'd like to have both modes running simultaneously.  I've spent most of the week getting this far... but need to ensure I'm heading down the right path with my plan.

Comment: "I need it to be real-time... and that means C++" that's a bold statement. What do you mean with real-time? *hard* real-time?

Comment: @stijn ... that's a fair question.  Since the ultimate goal would be to make a decision on the data acquired and react to what the camera is seeing, the data needs to be acquired and processed before what is moving in front of the camera is gone from the "sensing zone".  Since I plan to process data in blocks of 384x384 pixels, it seems reasonable that the specification is that a decision is made on the data before the next 384 pixels worth of data is available -- in other words, processing as fast as or faster than the camera is generating the data == "real-time".

Comment: I notice that I received a down-vote on my question.  It would be helpful for me to know why.

Answer (score 2):

To (1):

Makes sense to me. You'd have to be careful of synchronization issues when accessing the same buffer from GUI code and your receiver code otherwise. One possible refinement would be to limit the number of GUI updates a bit. Screen refresh rates are usually 50 or 60Hz and most GUI libraries assume that updates don't happen much more frequently than that.

You can also cut down on the amount of data that you copy by just copying what will actually be displayed on the screen. So I'd recommend maybe inverting this a little: The GUI gets an update timer (whatever looks good enough for your purpose) that pulls new display contents from the circular buffer as needed. That way you cut down on a lot of unnecessary (that is, invisible) screen updates and buffer copies.

Depending on your needs you could also just use the blocks that are created for part 2 of your question for screen updates.

To (2):
First, you don't normally need sockets or anything like that when you use multithreading.

I'd recommend something like a thread pool for your processing: As new blocks become available copy them to a task object (a class you define that has the code for processing and implements an interface understood by the thread pool) and give it to a thread pool.

Since you're using Qt I'd look at QThreadPool and QRunnable for this part. If you need to FINISH processing blocks in a specific order things get a bit more interesting. Basically you'd have a blocking queue data structure that you would also feed with the QRunnable objects, then another thread that grabs them off there and waits for each to complete in the order they were started.

The communication here would be limited to the data acquisition thread cutting the input into blocks and launching tasks. If you need to also control the data acquisition thread from the data processing tasks you'd likely need a bit of a different design.

You might also get away without using a real-time kernel patch. If the library you use to access your line scan camera buffers its input you would just get multiple lines one after the other if you miss an update. Again this depends on how fast you need to react, but you're doing image processing on blocks that are multiple lines high, so I'd expect that you can already handle a bit of delay.

ETA:
I just re-read your question. So you basically have blocks of only 384x384 pixels every 100ms. I was about to suggest using Qt signals but there you can run into problems: Qt signals use a blocking queue data structure internally when communicating between threads. Their implementation unfortunately does not allow you to set a size limit so if your GUI thread or your processing thread does not process them fast enough (say a user is in a modal dialog for the GUI) they will get buffered instead and use up memory.

Instead you can use something like this:

```
Acquisition thread ==> (Blocking Queue) ==> Processing thread
```

Basically, your acquisition thread would just pump blocks into the queue. The processing thread would grab blocks from the queue in a loop and send them to the GUI for display, then process them. Or the other way around if you want visualizations.

Comment: Great response.  I've researched QRunnable / QThreadpool and understand how to implement those.  Can you give me some guidance on a Blocking Queue?

Comment: After some searching I couldn't find an implementation of a blocking queue for C++ in a library, so I ended up implementing it myself using QQueue, mutexes and condition variables when I needed it. If you find one, I'd be interested as well.

Comment: Is there something generic you can share to get me pointed in the right direction?

Comment: I've got the plumbing in place for some of this.  Ignoring (1) "Live" view above and focusing on (2) data processing of blocks of data, I have a QThread that is acquiring data from the camera and emitting a signal when done, connected to a GUI slot.  This spawns a QRunnable to run the algorithm on the block generated.  This is all working, albeit in a "vaccum" (i.e., no real data).  I don't know the right way to pass the data around.  I am thinking of emitting a QVector from the QThread instance, and passing that as an argument to QRunnable.  But, I don't know how to pass the arg.