# Passing a QVector as arg to QRunnable

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, qvector

I am building a C++ application using Qt to acquire data from a line-scan camera running at 3000Hz.  In another question ([Using C++ to interface with a line-scan camera at 3000Hz, and process / display the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935956/using-c-to-interface-with-a-line-scan-camera-at-3000hz-and-process-display)) I received great advice as I planned my strategy to attack this.  I now have a specific issue.  I'll reiterate my disclaimer:  I am an engineer and not a programmer... but I'm learning as I go.

I'm using a `QThread` to continually acquire data into `QVector`.  I emit the `QVector` to the main GUI thread, which creates a `QRunnable` and passes it to a `QThreadPool` to process the block of data.  In this way, I plan to acquire blocks of data and create tasks to process and respond to those blocks in "real time".  To simply get all the pieces to function and compile, I originally used a single integer value as the payload.  I can continually generate a random *int* in the `QThread`, emit to the GUI thread, create a `QRunnable` and operate on the *int* in the thread pool.  I'm proud of that.  However, I can't get it to work with a `QVector`.  I run into several compiling errors, including:

```
main.cpp:12:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'qRegisterMetaType'
    qRegisterMetaType<QVector<unsigned short> >("QVector<unsigned short>");

main.cpp:12:47: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
    qRegisterMetaType<QVector<unsigned short> >("QVector<unsigned short>")
```

**EDIT: The above errors are obviously due to a missing `#include <QMetaType>` in main.cpp.  This, combined with information in all of the comments/answers below got the code to compile. **

Since I'm really swimming in the deep end here, I'm now resorting to simply blindly fiddling with the code trying to decipher error messages and try different things.  Here are all the individual files that comprise the project.  **Note, above all code that is my attempt to implement a QVector payload, I commented out the bits of code that works with `int` types.  Look for "// works with type int!"**  I know this is a long post, but I don't know how to simplify the MWE any further and still illustrate my problem, since I don't know where the issue with the QVector begins... hence all of the files.  I hope it emphasizes that I've really tried to get this to work.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMetaType> // Added based on comments provided on SO
#include "appwidget.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    AppWidget gui;
    gui.show();

    qRegisterMetaType<QVector<unsigned short> >("QVector<unsigned short>");

    return app.exec();
}
```

**appwidget.h**

```
#ifndef APPWIDGET_H
#define APPWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QThreadPool>

#include "acquire.h"
#include "algorithm.h"

class AppWidget : public QWidget
{ Q_OBJECT

 public:
  AppWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

 protected:
  Acquire thread;
  Algorithm task;

 private slots:
  //void processBlock(int);  // works with type int!
  void processBlock(const QVector<unsigned short>);

};

#endif
```

**appwidget.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <iostream>

#include "appwidget.h"

AppWidget::AppWidget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent), task({0}) //task(0)
{

    thread.liftoff();
    //connect(&thread, SIGNAL(blockAcquired(int)), this, SLOT(processBlock(int)));  // works with type int!
    connect(&thread, SIGNAL(blockAcquired(const QVector<unsigned short>)), this, SLOT(processBlock(const QVector<unsigned short>)));

    setWindowTitle(tr("TestApp"));
    resize(550, 400);

}

//void AppWidget::processBlock(int slot_arg)  // works with type int!
void AppWidget::processBlock(const QVector<unsigned short> slot_arg)
{
    std::cout << "GUI: received signal: " << &slot_arg << std::endl;
    Algorithm *task = new Algorithm(slot_arg);
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(task);
}
```

**acquire.h**

```
#ifndef ACQUIRE_H
#define ACQUIRE_H

#include <QVector>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QThread>
#include <QWaitCondition>

class Acquire : public QThread {

  Q_OBJECT

 public:
    Acquire(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Acquire();

    void liftoff();

 signals:
    //void blockAcquired(int);  // works with type int!
    void blockAcquired(const QVector<unsigned short>);

 protected:
    void run();

 private:
    QVector<unsigned short> image_buffer;
    QMutex mutex;
    QWaitCondition condition;

};

#endif
```

**acquire.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "acquire.h"

Acquire::Acquire(QObject *parent)
     : QThread(parent)
{
}

Acquire::~Acquire()
{
    std::cout << "Acquire thread: dying." << std::endl;
    wait();
}

void Acquire::liftoff()
{
    std::cout << "Acquire thread: init." << std::endl;
    start();
}

void Acquire::run()
{

    //int image_buffer; // works with type int!
    QVector<unsigned short> image_buffer(384 * sizeof(unsigned short) * 192);

    forever {

    /* // works with type int!
    image_buffer = rand() % (int)(65535 - 0 + 1);
    nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0, 800000*192}}, NULL);
    */

    int k=0;
    for (int i=0; i<384; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<192; j++) {
        image_buffer[k] = 0 + (rand() % (int)(65535 - 0 + 1));
        k++;
        }
        nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0, 800000}}, NULL);
    }

    //std::cout << "Acquire thread: block acquired: " << image_buffer << std::endl;  // works with type int!
    std::cout << "Acquire thread: block acquired: " << &image_buffer << std::endl;  

    //emit blockAcquired(image_buffer);  // works with type int!
    emit blockAcquired(image_buffer);
    }
}
```

**algorithm.h**

```
#ifndef ALGORITHM_H
#define ALGORITHM_H

#include <QRunnable>
#include <QThread>
#include <QVector>

class Algorithm : public QObject, public QRunnable
{
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  //Algorithm(int);  // works with type int!
  Algorithm(const QVector<unsigned short>);
  ~Algorithm();

  //int arg_passed;  // works with type int!
  const QVector<unsigned short> arg_passed;

 protected:
  void run();

};

#endif
```

**algorithm.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "algorithm.h"

//Algorithm::Algorithm(int i) // works with type int!
Algorithm::Algorithm(const QVector<unsigned short> arg_passed)
{
    // arg_passed = i;  // works with type int!
    std::cout << "Algorithm: init." << std::endl;
}

Algorithm::~Algorithm()
{
    std::cout << "Algorithm: dying." << std::endl;
}

void Algorithm::run()
{
    std::cout << "Algorithm: running, " << QThread::currentThread() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Arg: " << arg_passed << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `Algorithm task;` is a member variable of `AppWidget` so it is constructed when `AppWidget` is constructed. `Algorithm` objects require a QVector to initialize themselves with, so you must supply one. You'll need to include it in the initializer list for AppWidget's constructor.

Comment: @Slavik81 When using `int` types, I used `task(0)` in the initializer list.  How should it be different for a `QVector`?  I tried task({0}) among others...

Comment: `AppWidget::AppWidget():task(QVector<unsigned int>())` will fix the compile error. There are still a number of major issues, though.

Comment: For instance, you probably don't want to be using a pointer for `Algorithm::arg_passed`. Otherwise you might find the thing it points to being destroyed at an inopportune time. Just use a QVector directly: `const QVector<unsigned short> arg_passed;`

Comment: @Slavik81  That pointer was one of my "stabs in the dark".  It was originally just `const QVector<unsigned short> arg_passed;`  I'll update again.  Also, using `task(QVector<unsigned int>())` in the initializer list worked.  Thanks for that.  Now, there is an issue with qRegisterMetaType.  I'll update for that, also.  I know I'm over my head on this stuff, but that's how I'll learn.

Comment: I needed to `#include <QMetaType>` in main.cpp.  That was another *face palm*.  It has now compiled.

Answer (score 3):

The error message means that you're trying to use incomplete type. You need to add `#include <QVector>` to the top of `algorithm.h`.

Comment: That was definitely one of my issues (and, indeed, a *facepalm* issue).  I included `QVector`, but still can't compile.  I've editted my original question to include this correction.  See the updated error message.  I believe it has to do with an interaction with my class constructor for `Algorithm` and the `QVector` payload.

Comment: It seems that now you're missing `#include <QVector>` in the `main.cpp`.